# Two Form Threading in one Need:"MainForm" Load Behind "Splash Form"

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

Two Forms
 1. "SplashForm"
 2. "MainForm"

I want to load "MainForm" AS background Process of "SplashForm" process
when "SplashForm" process end i just want to show the "MainForm" which should be already loaded code

VB Code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Threading

Public Class MultiThreading
    ' Global declaration 
    Dim mf As New MainForm
    'Thread Declaration
    Dim tm As New Thread(AddressOf LoadProcess)
    Dim ts As New Thread(AddressOf Splashprocess)

    Private Sub Epaper_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Opacity = 0
        tm.Start()
        ts.Start()
    End Sub

    Sub  LoadProcess()
        mf.Show()
        mf.Hide()
    End Sub

    Sub Splashprocess()
        For i As Integer = 0 To 1000
            Me.Opacity += 0.01
        Next
        If Me.Opacity = 1 Then
            mf.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        End If
    End Sub
    End Class
```

Comment: Why are you threading the form loading like that? Instantiate the MainForm in a using SplashForm block ...when MainForm is instantiated, you can then call `Application.Run(MainForm);`

Comment: ...but I'm certain it wasn't this difficult to work with a splash screen ...it's been a year.

Comment: i also tried using delegate but failed to set Show() for main form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you call the SplashScreen from the main form?
Your main form should be invisible at first. When the main form is loaded, You could first of all show the splashscreen as an independant form (not child), then proceed on loading your main form. When all the process is done, dismiss the splashscreen and show the main form.

Therefore, you would avoid using homemade threads.

Here is a pseudo-code exemple :

```
In Main_Form class                // which is invisible
{
    When Main_Form is loaded
    {
        Show SplashScreen

        Proceed on loading everything else

        Hide SplashScreen
        Show Main_Form
    }
}
```

Comment: i am new to threading thank u for help Érik Ryk Desjardins and IAbstract and Lucifer.

Comment: Evolis Pebble printer VB Running want to use it in VB.NEt : please help i m not able to post question page said that ctrl+k your question not properly formatted!